# Why am I getting an error in the output of this prime testing program in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried out this code in Python for testing whether or not a number is prime.

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter a number:'))
for i in range (2, x):
    if (x % i) == 0:
        print (x, 'is not prime')
    else:
        print(x, 'is prime')
```

But when I entered 25 I get the following output.Why?

Why is the output printed for so many times?Also, why is there suddenly a line that says 25 is not a prime (correct) amidst so many 'is a prime'?
[image]

Comment: Because you call that `if` statement for every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Be more careful with your indentation. The code in your question doesn't match the code in your screenshot.

Comment: Read through your own code step by step. You're printing inside the `for` loop, which is causing both problems. If you have trouble visualizing your code, get a piece of paper and "simulate" the running of the program yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Your posted code doesn't produce the posted output.  The posted output should be text, not a screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looping from `2` to `x` for a value of x i.e. looping `x-2` times and you are printing for each iteration. Hence, **23** print statements for **`x = 25`**.

You can do something like this :

```
x = int (raw_input('Enter a number:'))
answer = "{} is prime"
for i in range (2,x):
    if (x%i)==0:
        answer = "{} is not prime"
        break
    else:
        pass
print(answer.format(str(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use break

```
x=int (raw_input('Enter a number:'))
for i in range (2,x):
    if (x%i)==0:
        print (x,'is not prime')
        break 
else:
    print(x,'is prime')
```

A positive integer greater than 1 which has no other factors except 1 and the number itself is called a prime number. So, it is good to check if variable x is greater than 1.

```
x=int (raw_input('Enter a number:'))
# prime numbers are greater than 1
if x > 1:
# check for factors
    for i in range(2,x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            print(x,"is not a prime number")
            print(i,"times",x//i,"is",x)
            break
    else:
        print(x,"is a prime number")

# if input number is less than
# or equal to 1, it is not prime
else:
   print(x,"is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 1):

when you run this code, python will continue executing code in a for loop for all i in that range.

when you input 25, python first divides it by 2. Since 25%2=1, it prints that it is prime

it does the same for 3 and 4 and prints that both are prime

at 5, it calculates that 25%5=0 and correctly prints that 25 is not prime

try this

`x=int (raw_input('Enter a number:'))
for i in range (2,x):
    if (x%i)==0:
        print(x,'is not prime')
        break
    elif i==x-1:
        print('x is prime')`

Python divides the number by i. If at any point the remainder is 0, it prints that the number is not prime and the code ends.

If the remainder is not zero, the code loops back to the beginning of the for loop

If x%i has never equaled zero by the second to last iteration (represented by i==x-1), then the code prints that x is prime

Answer (score 0):

use a **for** loop statements

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter a number:'))
for i in range(1, x):
    if x <= 2:
        print(x, 'is prime')
        break

    elif (x % i) == 0:
        print (x, 'is not prime')
        break

    else:
        print(x, 'is prime')
        break
```